# Carregar conteúdo dinamicamente com AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Eu tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
  <label id="meuTemplate" for="criaAssoc" class="instAssoc" style="display:none">

  <strong>ID:</strong>
    <input name="idInstrucao" type="text">
  <strong>Ordem:</strong>
    <input type="text">

  <span>
    <strong class="instTxt">Instrução:</strong>
    <textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
  </span>

  <img src="images/1.png" title="Remover instrução" class="botaoExcluir" >

</label>
```

Que tem o seguinte resultado como no print abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Através desse código JS (abaixo) usando jQuery ao clicar no botão mais posso clonar a label passada no HTML acima.

```
//Script para adicionar labels
var ids = 1;

$(".btnNewInst").click(function(){
    var novoId = "lb_" + (ids++);

    var clone = $("#meuTemplate").clone();
    clone.prop("id", novoId); // É necessário mudar o id depois que se clona
    $(".instAssoc:last").after("<br>", clone);
    clone.show();

    clone.find(".botaoExcluir").click(function() {
        clone
            .prev().remove().end() // Remove também o <br>
            .remove();
    });

});

//Disparando evento click para criar a primeira label
$(".btnNewInst").click();
```

O resultado da clonagem é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto eu utilizo um codigo JS usando Ajax para ler informações da minha base de dados. Mas, não consigo fazer isso label a label só consigo ter exito no primeiro label. Os seguintes que são clonados o Ajax não consegue rodar. E até consegue se a label já tiver sido clonado antes de ser disparado o evento que acione o Ajax, mas ele só roda na primeira label. A informação que era para sair na segunda não sai, só faz clonar a informação da primeira label. Segue um print da situação descrita.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o script que está o AJAX:

```
//Ajax para recuperar o texto da instrução passando o ID
$("input[name='idInstrucao']").focusout(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/instrucaoAjax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'idInstrucao='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: '',
        error: function(leitura){
            $("textarea").val(leitura);
        },
        success: function(leitura){      

            if(leitura == 1){
                $("textarea").val("Esta pergunta não existe!");    
            }else{
                $("textarea").val(leitura);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Alguma sugestão para este BUG?

**Atualização:**
Fiz as alterações como sugerido. Mas, o problema persiste. Agora não replica mais o resultado do primeiro label no segundo. Porém, não funciona nos label's clonados. Olhem como ficou meu script depois das alterações:

```
//Script para adicionar labels
var ids = 1;

$(".btnNewInst").click(function(){
    var novoId = "lb_" + (ids++);

    var clone = $("#meuTemplate").clone();
    clone.prop("id", novoId); // É necessário mudar o id depois que se clona
    $(".instAssoc:last").after("<br>", clone);
    clone.show();

    $(document).on('click', '.botaoExcluir', function() {
        $(this).closest('label')
            .prev().remove().end() 
            .remove();
    });

});

//Disparando evento click para criar a primeira label
$(".btnNewInst").click(); 

//Ajax para recuperar o texto da instrução passando o ID

$("input[name='idInstrucao']").focusout(function(){

    var valor = this.value;

    var self = this;

    var textArea= $(self).closest('label').find('textarea');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/instrucaoAjax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'idInstrucao='+valor,
        beforeSend: '',
        error: function(leitura){
            alert(leitura);
        },
        success: function(leitura){      

            if(leitura == 1){
                textArea.val("Esta pergunta não existe!");    
            }else{
                textArea.val(leitura);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o seu problema é o "scope"/escopo do `this` dentro do `$.ajax` que está no contexto errado, a apontar para a função ajax e não para o elemento que disparou o evento.

Tente assim:

```
$("input[name='idInstrucao']").focusout(function(){
    var valor = this.value; // ou var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/instrucaoAjax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'idInstrucao='+valor , // no caso de usar self, use 'idInstrucao='self.value
```

Para além disto, no caso de querer referenciar a `textarea` correcta podia fazer assim por exemplo:

```
        // antes de entrar na função ajax
        var self = this;
        var textArea= $(self).closest('label').find('textarea');

        // dentro da função sucesso do ajax:
        if(leitura == 1){
            textArea.val("Esta pergunta não existe!");    
        }else{
            textArea.val(leitura);
        }
```

---

Já agora, um outro problema, ou possível optimização, é esta parte do seu código:

```
clone.find(".botaoExcluir").click(function() {
    clone
        .prev().remove().end() // Remove também o <br>
        .remove();
});
```

Que me parece melhor fazer como em baixo e retirá-lo da função que gera um novo clone:

```
$(document).on('click', '.botaoExcluir', function() {
    $(this).closest('label')
        .prev().remove().end() 
        .remove();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Duas sugestões depois do seu código corrigido:

o método [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) aceita parametros, o primeiro é um booleano para poder fazer clone dos eventos. Isto estava a faltar à minha resposta, pois sem ele o novo input nunca dispara o `focusout`. Assim use: `var clone = $("#meuTemplate").clone(true);`

a segunda é repetida, tire este codigo em baixo para fora da função click, senão ele vai adicionar multiplos eventos. E não é preciso mais do que uma vez, uma vez que está delegado:

```
$(document).on('click', '.botaoExcluir', function() {
    $(this).closest('label')
        .prev().remove().end() 
        .remove();
});
```

Codigo completo [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wSxz/)

Comment: Yeah! Rodou... perfeitamente! Vlw @Sergio