# Executar arquivo PHP sem atualizar a página

Tags: php

Tenho uma lista de produtos, ao clicar em algum produto, irá para outro arquivo PHP e fazer os cálculos e voltar para a página de produtos.

Mas se eu clicar em um produto que esteja perto do rodapé, ou seja, lá em baixo na página, quando voltar nessa página de produto, o usuário vai voltar lá no topo do site, pois foi atualizado a página.

Como executar comandos de outro arquivo PHP ao ser clicado em um  IMAGEM  sem atualizar a página?

Tem como colocar algum exemplo, tipo:
IMAGEM DO PRODUTO

Arquivo (verifica.php) irá fazer:

```
<?php
$credito = "30.00";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$valor = $_GET['valor'];
if($valor > $credito){ 

echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> alert ('Você ultrapassou seu limite de crédito!'); window.location.href='carrinho.php'; </script>";

}else{

header("Location: produtos.php");

}

?>
```

Ou seja, quando voltar para página produtos.php irá atualizar a página, tem como não atualizar a página?

Comment: Você precisa usar [Ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info). Alguns exemplos [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisicao-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/site-em-uma-unica-pagina), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3324/carregar-conteudo-dinamicamente-com-ajax) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6299/carregar-post-sem-refresh-da-pagina-com-ajax-e-jquery).

Comment: Utilize AJAX, vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Tem como colocar algum exemplo, tipo:

<a href="verificar.php?id=1&valor=20.00">IMAGEM DO PRODUTO</a>

Arquivo (verifica.php) irá fazer:
<?php
$credito = "30.00";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$valor = $_GET['valor'];
if($valor > $credito){

echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
   alert ('Você ultrapassou seu limite de crédito!');
   window.location.href='carrinho.php';
   </script>";

}else{

header("Location: produtos.php");

}
?>

Ou seja, quando voltar para página produtos.php irá atualizar a página, tem como não atualizar a página?

Answer (score 0):

Cara o que você pode fazer é colocar os scripts dos produtos que estão dando erro na mesma página se for possível, se você colocar o código seria mais facil de entender.

Comment: Então, não está dando erro, apenas se o usuário clicou em um produto que esteja lá em baixo da tela, assim que terminar o processamento o usuário volta lá no topo, ou seja, atualizou a página...