# Carregar campos automaticamente com jquery e json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js

Preciso preencher meus campos, após selecionar um.

Meu JSON é da seguinte forma:

```
[{"codeVisit":"3EE","segmentVisit":"industria","streetVisit":"Rua Francisco Leandro Cunha","neighbVisit":"Vila","countryVisit":"Brasil","client":"5580262b600e53e82069bbeb"}]
```

E está no endereço: `/clienteJson`

Tenho os campos com os nomes abaixo no meu HTML(`input text`, exceto o client que é um `select`):

O campo `client` é um `select` e após seleciona-lo, preciso que os demais dados sejam carregados automaticamente.

Estou fazendo um *script* da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='client']").change(function(){
      var codeVisit= $("input[name='codeVisit']");
      var segmentVisit = $("input[name='segmentVisit']");
      $(codeVisit).val('Carregando...');
      $(segmentVisit).val('Carregando...');
        $.getJSON(
        "/clienteJson"          
        { client: $( this ).val() },
          function( json )
          {
            $( codeVisit ).val( json.codeVisit );
            var s = $( segmentVisit ).val( json.segmentVisit );
            console.log(s)
          }
        );
        alert("erro")
    });
  });
```

Porém os campos não são carregados.

O que posso fazer?

Estou usando nodejs e mongoose.

Comment: Você olhou o console do JavaScript pra ver a mensagem de erro? `/clienteJson` deveria ser uma string, e deveria ser sucedido por uma vírgula.

Comment: Além do que o @ctgPi falou, também não entendi pq tu pega os inputs e seta carregando

Comment: Agora eu reparei também que seu json começa `[{"codeVisit":3EE, …`; estão faltando aspas em torno de `3EE`. Como você está gerando esse JSON lá no servidor, exatamente?

Comment: O json esta correto, eu que editei e esqueci de incluir a aspas do 3EE, mas no json tem. e sobre o /clientJson, coloquei em ''" e virgula. Ainda assim nao funcionou.   O grande problema é que meu arquivo Json monta todas as informacoes(se tem 200, ele monta 200 arrays) . Quando envio {client: $(this).val}, ele busca pelo ID especifico, tanto que o erro no console é: http://localhost:3000/clientJson?client=5580262b600e53e82069bbeb Not Found....  Queria saber como buscar as informacoes sendo que meu json traz tudo.

Comment: Estou a ver que estás a corrigir erros no código... o resto do código é o que estás a usar? ou é código de exemplo? Por exemplo `client: $( this ).val() },` está errado... o problema é descrito aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3325/129

Comment: acabei de consertar. Agora esta ok! Sim o problema é com o client: $( this ).val() , porque como disse meu arquivo Json, a url abre com todos os dados...  Nao criei uma url com ID.  e esse client:$(this), busca na url o id . Queria saber como buscar os dados, sem ter que passar esse ID.  Ou seja, quando eu selecionar(select client), buscar no meu arquivo json os dados e preencher os demais.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON(
   "/clienteJson",         
   { client: $( this ).val() },
   function( json ){
      codeVisit.val( json[0].codeVisit );
      segmentVisit.val( json[0].segmentVisit );
   }
);
```

**Edit 1 -----------------**

O objeto resposta é uma array de um único elemento, logo:

```
array[0].propriedade
```

Para mais informações sobre a sintaxe do json, visite: http://json.org

Comment: O que esse código faz? Poderia completar sua resposta explicando como ele é capaz de resolver a pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='client']").change(function() {
        $.getJSON(
            "/clientsjson/" + this.value + "",
            function(json) {
                $("#codeClient").val(json.code);
                $("#segmentClient").val(json.segment);
                $("#sectorClient").val(json.sector);
                $("#industryClient").val(json.industry);
            }
        );
    });
});
```