# exportar arquivo json

Tags: node.js, express.js, mongoose

Estou usando nodejs, mongoose.

No controllers no final dou um `res.json(clientes);`
e na minha rota crio:
`app.get('/clientesjson/:id', isLoggedIn, cliente.clientesjson);`

Preciso acessar minhas informacoes Json pelo ID. Da forma atual, qualquer informacao que eu digitar no local de ID, irá abrir meu arquivo Json
Se eu digitar:

```
http://localhost:3000/clientesjson/qualquercoisa
```

Abrira o arquivo Json.

Quero saber como fazer para setar um id e só abrir a partir dele.

```
http://localhost:3000/clientesjson/43546575867gg556TT7
```

Answer (score 3):

Esse `:id` estará acessível no `req.params.id`. Assim tens de criar um middleware que use essa informação e que responda consoante.

Por exemplo:

```
//middleware
function usarId(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    // fazer algo aqui com o ID
    // por exemplo:
    res.locals.id = id;
}

app.get('/clientesjson/:id', isLoggedIn, usarId, cliente.clientesjson);
```

Se o que queres é verificar se um URL bate certo com um certo ID então podes fazer no middleware:

```
var userID = 'xpto';
function verificarId(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (id != userID) res.status(401).send('Esse ID não está correto');
}
```

Comment: Só tirar uma duvida. Estou fazendo isto para poder preencher automaticamente meus inputs apos setar um campo(select).   Com isto crio um jquery, que detalhei no link a seguir: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69528/carregar-campos-automaticamente-com-jquery-e-json?noredirect=1#comment142253_69528      .... Esta seria a melhor maneira, ou tem outra mais simples que criar um Json para isto?

Comment: @Nodejs vou seguir essa pergunta sobre como criar o JSON na outra pergunta então, para não misturarmos perguntas.